# How priorize multiple override?

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides

I am using Magento 1.13 Enterprise.
I have two custom modules which rewrite the core class `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` :

```
app
---code
------local
---------Mynamespace
------------BigFinder
------------Robots
```

In `app/code/local/Mynamespace/BigFinder/etc/config.xml` I have :

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite> 
                    <category_view>Mynamespace_BigFinder_Block_Catalog_Category_View</category_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global> </config>
```

And in `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Robots/etc/config.xml` I have :

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite> 
                    <category_view>Mynamespace_Robots_Block_Catalog_Category_View</category_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

I would like to keep my two modules and rewrite the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` class by `Mynamespace_BigFinder_Block_Catalog_Category_View`, and not by `Mynamespace_Robots_Block_Catalog_Category_View`.

How can priorize my rewrites ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to priorize a rewrite. The two config.xml files are merged in an order dependent by the filesystem: so you could have one rewrite in an environment and a different one in another, while keeping the code still.

You should avoid using rewrites as much as possible. If you have to, use just one. You can still override multiple times having the rewrite extends all the other files in a row.

For example: Mynamespace_BigFinder_Block_Catalog_Category_View could extend Mynamespace_Robots_Block_Catalog_Category_View, and
Mynamespace_Robots_Block_Catalog_Category_View could extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Catalog_Category_View
In this example you still need just one in config: the one for Mynamespace_BigFinder_Block_Catalog_Category_View.

If you do so for a controller (in controllers folder), you could have to require_once the parent before.